# Search results went invisible in google

Tags: google-search

we have countered a seriously weird problem. 3 of our very most popular search results went invisible. This means, that they still show avg. position, they still get impressions. But they don't get clicks / traffic.

Its been 5 days since it happened. There is no messages in regards to those pages or manual actions (delay of up to 3 days). Absolutely everything is green. And the live testing tool is green as well. There has been no DMCAS (dmca has delay of 2-4 days).

With all the years we have been doing business, we have encountered all possible situations with google. But this is something unique. The results are simply put invisible and other content from our site wont pop up, as it gets labeled as "irrelevant" as the main URL is there (but invisible.)

**Is there some sort of a algorithm that detects X anomyalies and makes specific results into invisible until manual review by a googler?**

Answer (score 0):

There can be possibly four reasons for this issue;

1. The site is too new and Google hasn’t had the chance to crawl it yet.
2. The site content is hidden from search engines .
3. The site content isn’t optimized for search engines.
4. The target keyword market is too competitive.
5. The site has been penalized by Google.

Have you click bomb your links or someone else?

As you said that you see the avg position and impression for the page, than this might be manual penalty. Wait for Google's answer or hit the google webmaster forum. In case of manual penalty, it will take time to make effect on SERP.

Comment: 5 year old site. Content is available and optimised. Keywords are on point and there are no competition. Only thing is penalisation, but its 3 specific urls the rest of the million urls are working fine and ranking as they should. Click bombing? Never heard of it, but the position of our url was number 1 and it was highly targeted and got alot of clicks. Analytic shows, that they were all quality from various sources.

Comment: Manual action does make sense, but ive never seen a manual action for just 3 urls, while the other same structured pages are fine. Also, the links are not deindexed, but they are invisible. The impressions are getting counted in the search console.
I would write to Google product forums, but whats the point? They are as about useful there as wet towel.